# Updating primary keys using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm currently working on a sandbox environment based on two databases located on different servers. What I am aiming to do is allow my clients to make changes on a test server and then once approved, I can simply hit a button and import the data across to my live database.

So far, I have managed to port the data across the two databases but what I would like to do is amend the primary keys on the test server to match those held on the live (incase I need backups and so that I can make checks to stop the same information being copied multiple times).

So far I have tried this solution:

```
 DT_SitePage OldPage = new DT_SitePage
                {
                    PageID = SP.PageID
                };

                DT_SitePage NewPage = new DT_SitePage
                {
                    PageID = int.Parse(ViewState["PrimaryKey"].ToString())
                };

                Sandbox.DT_SitePages.Attach(NewPage, OldPage);
                Sandbox.SubmitChanges();
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
***Value of member 'PageID' of an object of type 'DT_SitePage' changed.
A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.***
```

Is there anyway in LINQ to avoid this error and force the database to update this field???

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use the stock backup/restore functionality supplied by DB manufacturer?

It makes a perfect logical sense that high-level ORM tools won't allow you to change the primary key of the record, as they only identify the record by its primary key.

You should consider making direct `UPDATE` queries to DB from your code instead.

And anyway, changing the primary key is the bad idea, what prevents you from `INSERT`ing it with the needed value in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As said, modifying primary keys is typically something you don't want to do. If Linq-to-sql wouldn't have the early warning, your RDBMS would probably complain (SQL server does!). Especially when records are related by foreign key constraints updating primary keys is not trivial.

In cross-database scenarios, it is more common to use some "global" unique identification, for which GUIDs may do. Maybe your data can be identified in an alternative way? (Like when two users have the same name, they are deemed identical).

If you don't need to keep identical the database structures, you may consider using an extra field in your test database to store the "live" primary key.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265891/best-practice-for-synchronizing-common-distributed-data) is a post with lots of useful thoughts.